# Java writing byte array over JNI using O_direct

Tags: java, c, linux, java-native-interface

I am trying to use `O_direct` in Java over JNI in Linux.
here is the java part:

```
public class jnitest {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("jnitest"); // Load native library at runtime
                                       // hello.dll (Windows) or libhello.so (Unixes)
    }
    private native void test();
    private native void write(String path, byte[] chunkpayload);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            jnitest t=new jnitest();
            byte[] chunk=new byte[5];
            chunk[0]=1;
            chunk[1]=2;
            chunk[2]=3;
            chunk[3]=4;
            chunk[4]=5;
            String s="outtest";
            t.write(s,chunk);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("fehler lol");
        }
    }
}
```

This is the C part:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "jnitest.h"
#define BLOCKSIZE 512

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_jnitest_write(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jstring jpath, jbyteArray jchunkpayload){
    const char *path=(*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, jpath, 0);
    printf("path=%s \n",path);
    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, jpath, path);
    int len = (*env)->GetArrayLength (env,jchunkpayload);
    printf("lenght= %d \n",len);
    unsigned char* payload =(*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env,jchunkpayload,0);
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<len-1;i++){
        printf("%02x \n",(int)payload[i]);  
    }
    void *buffer; 
    int fd = open(path, O_SYNC|O_APPEND|O_CREAT|O_DIRECT);
    posix_memalign(&buffer,BLOCKSIZE,BLOCKSIZE);
    memcpy(buffer,payload,len);
    write(fd,buffer,BLOCKSIZE);
    printf("writen to file\n");
    (*env)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(env,jchunkpayload,payload,JNI_ABORT);
    free(buffer);
    return;
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_jnitest_test(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj){
    printf("test\n");
    return;
}
```

The program does not fail but the data is never written. I know I can use JNA, but i want to use JNI.  Does somebody have a working example for writing a byte array in java over JNI using `O_direct`?

Comment: You never check the return from `open()`, `posix_memalign()`, or `write()`.  You also `memcpy()` a total of `len` bytes to a `BLOCKSIZE` buffer.

Comment: Nor do you `close()` the file you may or may not have successfully opened.